# Multiple Rules in JUnit

Tags: java, junit4

I have defines two rules defined in one of the test class but the weird thing is only one of them works at a time - the one defined last.

```
@Rule public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();    
@Rule public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();
```

I cant figure out for the life of me how to define two or more rules and use them separately

Comment: What do you mean by "only one of them works at a time" can you provide some more example code, showing how you are using the rules in your test code and say what is not working correctly?

Comment: Well if I define both Rules and in one test if I was to use `folder.something()` and in the other `exception.expect(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)` then the exception rule wouldn't work as it was defined first

Comment: I don't see an error in the two code lines -- This should work. Could you please post the code of your entire test class.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem, and i found that in that case you can use the RuleChain, like that:

```
public TemporaryFolder temp;
public ExpectedException thrown;

@Rule
public TestRule chain =
    RuleChain.outerRule(temp = new TemporaryFolder())
             .around(thrown = ExpectedException.none());
```

An other example you can see [here](http://www.hascode.com/2012/02/ordering-your-junit-rules-using-a-rulechain/), and the [RuleChain javadoc](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html) also can help.

Comment: <rant>This works, although I don't understand why rules can't be accumulated and executed in the order in which they're declared.  In each test class where I wan't to use a second rule I have to define this chain?  And is it really a chain? Looks like a hierarchy.</rant>